# Sybase JConnect: ENABLE_BULK_LOAD usage

Tags: java, bulkinsert, sap-ase, bulk

Can anyone out there provide an example of bulk inserts via JConnect (with `ENABLE_BULK_LOAD`) to Sybase ASE?

I've scoured the internet and found nothing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got in touch with one of the engineers at Sybase and they provided me a code sample. So, I get to answer my own question.

Basically here is a rundown, as the code sample is pretty large... This assumes a lot of pre initialized variables, but otherwise it would be a few hundred lines. Anyone interested should get the idea. This can yield up to 22K insertions a second in a perfect world (as per Sybase anyway).

```
SybDriver sybDriver = (SybDriver) Class.forName("com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver").newInstance();
sybDriver.setVersion(com.sybase.jdbcx.SybDriver.VERSION_6);
DriverManager.registerDriver(sybDriver);

//DBProps (after including normal login/password etc.
props.put("ENABLE_BULK_LOAD","true");

//open connection here for  sybDriver

dbConn.setAutoCommit(false);    
String SQLString = "insert into batch_inserts (row_id, colname1, colname2)\n values (?,?,?) \n";

PreparedStatement   pstmt;
try
{
   pstmt = dbConn.prepareStatement(SQLString);      
}
catch (SQLException sqle)
{
   displaySQLEx("Couldn't prepare statement",sqle);
   return;
}

for (String[] val : valuesToInsert)
{
   pstmt.setString(1, val[0]);  //row_id    varchar(30)
   pstmt.setString(2, val[1]);//logical_server varchar(30)
   pstmt.setString(3, val[2]);  //client_host varchar(30)

   try
   {
      pstmt.addBatch();
   }
   catch (SQLException sqle)
   {
      displaySQLEx("Failed to build batch",sqle);
      break;
   }
}

try {
   pstmt.executeBatch();
   dbConn.commit();
   pstmt.close();
} catch (SQLException sqle) {
   //handle
}

try {
   if (dbConn != null)
      dbConn.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
   //handle
}
```

Comment: Did you actually prove this is working?  I am trying to get array inserts working from Java, and it is *slower* than row by row inserts. I repeatedly call addBatch to generate a batch of records and then called executeBatch to process them, but the results are not like I would expect. Also, no matter if I set "ENABLE_BULK_LOAD","true" or not it makes no difference to the runtime, making me think my code is not working as intended.

Comment: Hi Stephen, yes we managed to get it working. At last count I was able with batches around 50 in size to almost increase the rate by a magnitude over row-by-row.

Answer (score 4):

After following most of your advice we didn't see any improvement over simply creating a massive string and sending that across in batches of ~100-1000rows with a surrounding transaction. we got around:
*Big String Method [5000rows in 500batches]: 1716ms  = ~2914rows per second.
(this is shit!).

Our db is sitting on a virtual host with one CPU (i7 underneath) and the table schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE
archive_account_transactions
(
account_transaction_id INT,
entered_by INT,
account_id INT,
transaction_type_id INT,
DATE DATETIME,
product_id INT,
amount float,
contract_id INT NULL,
note CHAR(255) NULL
)
```

with four indexes on account_transaction_id (pk), account_id, DATE, contract_id.

Just thought I would post a few comments first we're connecting using:

```
jdbc:sybase:Tds:40.1.1.2:5000/ikp?EnableBatchWorkaround=true;ENABLE_BULK_LOAD=true
```

we did also try the .addBatch syntax described above but it was marginally slower than just using java StringBuilder to build the batch in sql manually and then just push it across in one execute statement. Removing the column names in the insert statement gave us a surprisingly large performance boost it seemed to be the only thing that actually effected the performance. As the Enable_bulk_load param didn't seem to effect it at all nor did the EnableBatchWorkaround we also tried DYNAMIC_PREPARE=false which sounded promising but also didn't seem to do anything.

Any help getting these parameters actually functioning would be great! In other words are there any tests we could run to verify that they are in effect? I'm still convinced that this performance isn't close to pushing the boundaries of sybase as mysql out of the box does more like 16,000rows per second using the same "big string method" with the same schema.

Cheers
Rod

Comment: Thanks this really helped me boost the peformnce 100K records in 2 minutes came down to 9 seconds !!!!

Comment: This is the most useful answer here - creating a gigantic string with all insert statements and send it across improves performance - substantially. Thanks @Rod

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the sample provided by Chris Kannon working, do not forget to disable auto commit mode first:

```
dbConn.setAutoCommit(false);
```

And place the following line before dbConn.commit():

```
pstmt.executeBatch();
```

Otherwise this technique will only slowdown the insertion.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how to do this in Java, but you can bulk-load text files with LOAD TABLE SQL statement. We did it with Sybase ASA over JConnect.

Comment: LOAD TABLE is unfortunately an ASA and iAnywhere only command from what I can find.

Comment: INPUT INTO is an alternative to LOAD TABLE, but again, I only used ASA and don't know if it is available in ASE.

Answer (score -2):

**Support for Batch Updates**

Batch updates allow a Statement object to submit multiple update commands
as one unit (batch) to an underlying database for processing together.

**Note:** To use batch updates, you must refresh the SQL scripts in the sp directory
under your jConnect installation directory.
CHAPTER

**See BatchUpdates.java in the sample** (jConnect 4.x) and sample2 (jConnect
5.x) subdirectories for an example of using batch updates with Statement,
PreparedStatement, and CallableStatement.
jConnect also supports dynamic PreparedStatements in batch.

**Reference:**

http://download.sybase.com/pdfdocs/jcg0420e/prjdbc.pdf

http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-jcarc/jcg0520e/prjdbc/@ebt-link;hf=0;pt=7694?target=%25N%14_4440_START_RESTART_N%25#X

.

**Other Batch Update Resources**

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/spec2/jdbc2.1.frame6.html

http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=5079

Comment: Nice copy paste. Unfortunately it has nothing about ENABLE_BULK_LOAD or array insert usage.