# How do you LOAD TABLE in Sybase IQ from a client using Java?

Tags: java, jdbc, sap-iq

Is it possible to load a file from a client computer into a table in Sybase IQ, using the LOAD TABLE ... USING CLIENT FILE statement?

The data does not come from a database, but rather an external source.

Can this be done using a JDBC driver in Java, and having the file only on the client computer?

If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, and a "proof-of-concept" this is the answer I have come up with:

Use the iAnywhere JDBC Driver, which is part of the SQL Anywhere Studio suite of software from SyBase. It is not limited to the TDS protocol, which the standard jConnect JDBC driver from SyBase is.

http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1037304

Note: This is not a Type 4 driver, and is not pure Java.

Comment: Nicolai, I ran into the same issue. After reading your post I switched over to the iAnywhere JDBC Driver. I am on Windows so I configured an ODBC Data Source for DBODBC11.dll. In my java project I am using jodbc.jar from SQL Anywhere 11. My connection string is pretty simple. "jdbc:ianywhere:DSN=dw". I can get a connection, but I now get the following error: [Sybase][ODBC Driver][Sybase IQ]Syntax error near 'LOAD'. Any Ideas? What exactly did you have to do in order to get this to work? Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry but I haven't really touched this stuff, since last year. I don't really remember what we did, and the code was a throw away "proof of concept" so I am afraid I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : [Sybase JConnect: ENABLE_BULK_LOAD usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112395/sybase-jconnect-enable-bulk-load-usage)
Also, you may want to try bcp.

Comment: I have already seen that answer, but that is for Sybase ASE. I want to use Sybase IQ, and the fastest way to get data into IQ as I understand it, is "LOAD TABLE..."